# Sustituir color de fondo por una imagen con css

Tags: javascript, php, css

Tengo hecho un juego, el Space Invaders, ahora mismo está creado pero los personajes, disparos, etc. son cuadrados, cada uno con un color, me gustaría sustituirlos por imágenes para completar el juego y que sea más real pero no lo consigo, he quitado el color de fondo, probado con background-image, etc.. pero nada, alguien tiene alguna idea, el juego funciona perfectamente, es cuestión del CSS, muchas gracias por todos, este es el código del style.css:

Si hago inspecciono la página, SI coge la imagen, pero aun así se ve en blanco, ¿puede ser el tamaño de la imagen?

```
.grid {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    border: solid black 1px;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.grid div {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
}

.invader {
    background-color: purple;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.shooter {
    background-color: green;
    background-image: url("imgs/rey.jpg");
}

.laser {
    background-color: orange;
}

.boom {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Necesitas agregar más código. Si es posible todo... acá solo podemos entender que a `.shooter` le estas dando background image, pero no sabemos en donde esta.

Comment: Dices que se ve blanco, pero el *shooter* parece ser verde, será que no has definido las dimensiones del mismo? Qué pasa si le das un width y height manualmente?

Comment: el problema estaba en el tamaño de la imagen que le estaba pasando, al tener el fondo blanco mostraba los 20 pixeles del tamaño de la imagen que cogia que correspondian a parte blanca de la imagen, he ampliado el tamaño de todo al doble y reducido la imagen y ya va bien, muchas gracias a todos